# How could I split commas excepts it's in double quotes

Tags: ruby

```
s1 ='a,b,c,"x,y,z" '
m1 = s1.split(',')
```

`"x,y,z"` should not be splitted by comma

The expected result should be ['a','b','c',"x,y,z"], total size is `4`

How could I do that in Ruby

Comment: You've asked nearly 500 questions, take a few minutes to learn [how to format code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You look like you're trying to parse CSV. You should use the `csv` gem. Don't try to manually parse CSV; it's complicated and most of the time it's better to use the gem.

Comment: OK, I will try `csv` gem , thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`csv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) module:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'csv'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> CSV.parse_line('a,b,c,"x,y,z"')
=> ["a", "b", "c", "x,y,z"]
```

Comment: Not a gem, core Ruby module.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, fixed. (Technically stdlib != core, either, but that's just being pedantic.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s1 ='a,b,c,"x,y,z" '

quotes = s1.match(/".+"/)

s1.split(/,(?![#{quotes}])|,(?=")/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be? Is it possible? Do I finally have a chance to use Ruby's bordering-on-bizarre [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop)?

Let's try:

```
str ='a,b,c,"x,y,z",d,e,"1,2,3",f '

u = ''  
str.split(?,).each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  t = s.strip
  if (t[0]==?") .. (t[-1]==?")
    u = '' if t[0]==?"
    u << t
    if t[-1]==?"
      a << u
    else
      u << ?,
    end
  else
    a << t
  end
end
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "\"x,y,z\"", "d", "e", "\"1,2,3\"", "f"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a one liner def like this that will separate the string by commas, unless the commas are inside simple OR double quotes

```
def separate params
  params.split(/(?!\B\b('|")[^\"']*),(?![^\"']*('|")\B\b)/)
end
```